# Kafka consumer doesn't receive messages until restarted

Tags: apache-kafka

I have tried both Kafka 0.8.2.2 and 0.9.0.0 and am seeing the same issue on both, which is this:

I start a fresh Zookeeper and Kafka server (empty data/log directories), start the consumer process for "mytopic", start the producer process for "mytopic", and then send a message through producer. **The consumer does not receive the message until it is restarted.**

I have tried configuring the consumer with both "earliest" and "latest" consumer offset reset strategies.

My question is - is this expected behavior? If so, is there a way to change it. If not, what is going on here?

Comment: Can you share commands you are providing or any code?

Comment: Are you using the command line clients to start up producers and consumers? At what point are you starting the Producer and Consumer in regards to creating the topic?

Comment: Interesting question. but need more details.

Comment: @morganw09dev I am using the new Kafka Consumer and Producer libraries (0.9), and am allowing the topics to be auto-created.

Comment: Are you using Python or Java Kafka consumer?

Answer (score -1):

If you start the consumer first with a topic that doesn't exist yet but will be auto-created by the Kafka broker this might be the same behavior as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975747/why-does-kafka-consumer-takes-long-time-to-start-consuming). Can you try whether the solution mentioned there solves your issue?